# What data structure should I use for this particular situation?

Tags: java, algorithm

**This is not a homeowrk problem**

I am designing a parking lot and lets say I have a variable `used` that counts how many spots are used and a `Hashmap` that maps car VIN numbers to parking lot numbers.

I start with `used = 0`

When CarA arrives:

```
used = used + 1;
h.put("CarA" , used) //CarA-> 1
```

When CarB arrives:

```
used = used + 1;
h.put("CarB" , used) //CarB-> 2
```

When CarC arrives:

```
used = used + 1;
h.put("CarC" , used) //CarC-> 3
```

At this point `used` contains 3

Now I remove CarA.

```
used = used - 1 // used contains 2
```

Question:
But now I need to keep track of the fact that slot 1 is empty and I should not forget to use it again for any other car. How do I keep track of the fact?

**My solution** (which I'd like to improve upon and get critiques on) is that I can keep such lot numbers ( freed up on removing cars) in a queue and as cars come if the queue is not empty I should simply use slots in the queue until queue is empty.

Comment: If you have a solution, what's your question?

Comment: Does the idea of "buddy memory allocation" help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation

Comment: @TedHopp I added clarification.

Comment: @HowardGuo - I seriously doubt that it helps ... unless you are proposing that the car park should change the parking slots boundaries based on the size of the cars.  (And I'd love to hear how you proposed to implement *that* in the real world!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is fine, except it does not need to be a queue: any data structure with `O(1)` insertion and `O(1)` removal will do. For example, using a stack in place of a queue will give you the same performance.

This idea is similar to using look-aside lists for memory buffers: rather than allocating a new resource (in your case, a new parking spot) check a collection of freed-up resources first to see if there is an item available for reuse. An added benefit of this approach is that you have a "high watermark" available to you at all times, telling you how many cars you have had at the peak.

Answer (score 0):

A free list is a data structure used in a scheme for dynamic memory allocation. It operates by connecting unallocated regions of memory together in a linked list, using the first word of each unallocated region as a pointer to the next. It's most suitable for allocating from a memory pool, where all objects have the same size.

Free lists make the allocation and deallocation operations very simple. To free a region, one would just link it to the free list. To allocate a region, one would simply remove a single region from the end of the free list and use it. If the regions are variable-sized, one may have to search for a region of large enough size, which can be expensive.

Source : http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-free-list.htm

Useful link : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/rac.920/a96598/freelist.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could create a queue/list of empty slots, but this could be over engineering. If you know all spaces range for 0 to n, you simply search the map until it returns null for a space.

An alternate is maintain two maps, empty spaces and full spaces. Your code will only move values from one to the other. To get an an available space from the available map, get an Iterator and get the next() element.

But again, over engineering. The simplest solution is that the map is the single point of truth for cars in spaces. You know a space is available because the map returns null when you check the contents of a space.

Calling map.size() will tell you how many spaces are used. If this equals your total available spaces, you know the lot is full.